# Oracle 19c cannot shrink blob column

Tags: oracle, shrink, blob, oracle-19c

I deleted a bunch of old data from a schema, including BLOB data, and afterwards I tried to shrink and compact everything. I managed to shrink all tables (enable row movement, shrink space compact, disable row movement), except the one BLOB column, which is stored on a separate segment:

```
SELECT
    segment_name,
    SUM(bytes) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 AS "GB_SIZE"
FROM
    dba_segments
WHERE
    owner = 'MY_OWNER'
GROUP BY
    segment_name
ORDER BY
    SUM(bytes) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 DESC;
```

Segment in question:

```
SEGMENT_NAME                GB_SIZE
SYS_LOB0000072887C00005$$   0,35955810546875
```

Note: this is a test DB, in prod DB, this is about 660 GB.

When I try to shrink it, I get this error:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY LOB ( my_blob ) ( SHRINK SPACE );

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
alter table my_table modify lob (my_blob) (shrink space)
Error report -
ORA-10635: Invalid segment or tablespace type
10635. 00000 -  "Invalid segment or tablespace type"
*Cause:    Cannot shrink the segment because it is not in auto segment space
           managed tablespace or it is not a data, index or lob segment.
*Action:   Check the tablespace and segment type and reissue the statement
```

Segment details:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    dba_segments
WHERE
    segment_name = 'SYS_LOB0000072887C00005$$';
```

Relevant details:

- Segment type: LOBSEGMENT
- Segment subtype: SECUREFILE
- Tablespace name: MY_DATA

Tablespace details:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    dba_tablespaces
WHERE
    tablespace_name = 'MY_DATA';
```

Relevant details:

- Extent management: LOCAL
- Allocation type: SYSTEM
- Segment space management: AUTO

Exact Oracle version:

Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

As far as I can tell, everything is as it should be, so I'm not sure what is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SHRINK SPACE` option is not supported for Securefile LOBs.

You may use `DBMS_REDEFINITION` (mostly online) or `ALTER TABLE ... MOVE LOB (...)`  (offline, table is locked during move).

[ORA-10635: Invalid Segment or Tablespace Type Error When Attempting To Shrink SOA-INFRA LOB [To Free Tablespace] (Doc ID 2382484.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2382484.1)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find this info for some reason. I'll try with the DBMS_REDEFINITION package.